# How to unpack WAR and all contained libs using maven

Tags: java, maven, plugins

In a Maven multi-module project one module needs all the classes contained in a WAR (produced by another module) and the classes of the contained JARs in its classpath (or better to say a plugin used in that module needs them in the classpath).

Unpacking the WAR and copying WEB-INF/classes to target/classes using dependency- and resources-plugins is done (as WAR can be referenced as a dependency).

But how can I unpack all (!) the JARs in WEB-INF/lib to target/classes?

Or more general: is there a plugin that is able to unpack all JARs found in a folder WITHOUT referencing each?

Answer (score 0):

There is maven-copy-plugin from evgeny-goldin which can do it. Here is an example:

```
<resource>
  <targetPath>${project.build.outputDirectory}</targetPath>
  <directory>${project.basedir}/some/dir</directory>
  <include>**/*.zip</include>
  <unpack>true</unpack>
</resource>
```

Unfortunately it doesn't work with Maven 3.0.0 or newer and the author has discontinued it. Because of this I created a [fork](https://github.com/jboesl/maven-plugins) which works again. I'm using it in my projects and is working well. It is not published at maven central so you'll have to build it on your own.

Answer (score 0):

As I've found no satisfying solution (official release, compatible with maven 3, easy to use, ...) I've decided to fork the plugin hat needs the additional classes and add the possibility to define additional classpath elements.

That was no big effort and I only have to unzip the WAR (using dependency plugin) and point these classpath elements to WEB-INF/classes and WEB-INF/lib/*.jar.

Thanks for your effort.